# XSLT or JavaScript - Remove duplications

Tags: javascript, arrays, xslt, distinct

I'm producing a list of radio buttons that's looking at a list of items containing individual countries and associated regions. Below is the XSL for my radio buttons

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <div id="filter">
        <xsl:call-template name="container" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="container">  
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>    
      <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
         <xsl:call-template name="group-items"/>
      </xsl:for-each>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="group-items">    
  <label class="region-filter-item" region="{@Region}">
    <input type="radio" name="region" class="regionbox">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Region"/>
    </input>
  </label>
```

This produces the correct data, but it also duplicates many of the regions because if there are 15 countries in one region, that one region will be displayed 15 times.

What's the best way to only show each region once?

Comment: We would need to see what your XML looks like, and some more of your XSLT.

Comment: Hi JLRishe - There isn't XML available. I'm using a Content Management system which contains a list. This list contains two columns, a country and a region. Each country has an associated region. I'm using XSL to surface this information. I've updated the XSL to show my full code.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing you must know the structure of the XML, because otherwise you wouldn't have been able to write any XSLT in the first place ;). But in any case, this sounds very much like a grouping problem. Are you using XSLT1.0 or XSLT2.0 here?

Comment: I'm using a content management system that stores everything in the list. I can reference the internal column names, and that's how  the XSLT can be written. I've worked out an alternative approach in this thread. Thanks for the responses all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a JavaScript function that pushes each unique item into an array, and then use the array to populate my container. All resolved. Thanks for all the help guys:)

```
function removeDuplicates(){
var Array = new Array();
$('#filter > .filter-item').each(function(){
    var country = $(this).attr('country ');         
    if ( $.inArray(region, Array ) == -1 ) {
        Array .push(region);
    }
}); 
Array .sort();

var length = Array .length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    $('#filter-container').find('.container').append('<label class="filter-item" country="' + Array [i] + '">' 
                                                + '<input type="radio" name="country" class="checkbox">' 
                                                    + Array [i] + 
                                                '</input>' + 
                                        '</label> ');
    }
```

}